# Remove double multiple ways SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a tag system and there is just one query that I cant figure out.
Here's what I have:

table column called tags in which there are these things for example:

Row 1: php

Row 2: php, html

Row 3: html, css, javascript

Row 4: php, css

What query can I use to only return these 4: php, html, javascript and css and nothing else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

Like you see now this will only give you headaches. Normalize your table first.

Comment: Yes, normalization would be required. I believe your table will not have only the values which you have given in the example and that it would get even more complex as your data increases.

Comment: Search on here for mysql multicolumn values. You'll find loads of questions and answers from people who've made the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your method for storing tags is really, really bad (as pointed out elsewhere).  You should have a table `post_tags` (or something like that) that has a row for each post (or whatever) and each tag on the post.

Sometimes, though, you cannot control such data structures.  Here is a method to get the first three tags out of the list.  You should be able to generalize this for any finite number of tags:

```
select distinct substring_index(substring_index(tags, ', ', n.n), ', ', -1) as tag
from table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach

> Code is for SQL SERVER - needs to be changed to work with MySQL

```
DECLARE @tag_list VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tag_part VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tag_part_len INT

DECLARE tag_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT tag
FROM TagData

OPEN tag_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor 
INTO @tag

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @tag_list IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @tag_list = @tag
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WHILE(LEN(@tag)>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @tag_part_len = CHARINDEX(',',@tag,0)

            IF @tag_part_len = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @tag_part_len = LEN(@tag)+1
                SET @tag_part = SUBSTRING(@tag,0,@tag_part_len)
                IF CHARINDEX(@tag_part,@tag_list,0) = 0 
                    SET @tag_list = @tag_list + ', ' + @tag_part
                SET @tag = ''
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @tag_part = SUBSTRING(@tag,0,@tag_part_len)
                IF CHARINDEX(@tag_part,@tag_list,0) = 0 
                    SET @tag_list = @tag_list + ', ' + @tag_part
                SET @tag = REPLACE(@tag,@tag_part+',','')
            END
        END
    END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor 
   INTO @tag
END

CLOSE tag_cursor
DEALLOCATE tag_cursor

SELECT @tag_list
```